# Intersect with MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT friend_id FROM friendships WHERE user_id = 1;

Returns:
+-----------+
| friend_id |
+-----------+
|         2 |
|         3 |
+-----------+

SELECT friend_id FROM friendships WHERE user_id = 2;

Returns:
+-----------+
| friend_id |
+-----------+
|         1 |
|         3 |
|         6 |
+-----------+
```

I'm trying to find an alternative to INTERSECT for MySQL. I need to get the common row(s) between these two queries.

Comment: See, for instance, JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join to replace the `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT f1.friend_id 
FROM friendships f1
JOIN friendships f2 ON f1.friend_id = f2.friend_id
WHERE f1.user_id = 1 and f2.user_id = 2;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, however I had to change `friend_id` to `f1.friend_id`. Thank you.

Comment: Yes sorry I missed that from my answer. I’ve updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Select A.friend_id from

(SELECT friend_id FROM friendships WHERE user_id = 1 ) A

join

(SELECT friend_id FROM friendships WHERE user_id = 2) B on A.friend_id = B.friend_id

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this query?

Since we are trying to find the mutual friends between user 1 and user 2,
by selecting friend_id from friendships and (user_id=1 or user_id =2) gives us the list of friends both users have. When group by friend_id and having count(friend_id)>1 are used, we are querying the friends that they have in common.

```
SELECT friend_id FROM friendships
WHERE user_id = 1 or user_id=2
GROUP BY friend_id
Having count(friend_id)>1
```